# Lost macOS boot option after using EaseUS partition to resize Windows partition

Tags: macos, windows, bootcamp, partition, diskutil

I am using a Macbook Air. After I installed Windows 10, I wanted to resize the Windows Partition and create a new partition to use data.

After that, Windows informs me that a recovery error - cannot boot to Windows. And I reinstall Windows again.

Then after I can enter to Windows desktop, bootcamp informs me that "could not locate macOS volume"

Then I get this error.

The option to boot to macOS has disappeared, only Windows remains.

Then I use DiskUtil to check. The macOS volume partition type is marked as "unknown".

Comment: Precisely which model of MacBook Air & what macOS was on it? See also https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/340344/i-can-no-longer-boot-into-macos-after-resizing-my-bootcamp-partition-in-easeus?rq=1 and https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/252287/i-can-no-longer-boot-into-macos-after-resizing-my-bootcamp-partition?noredirect=1&lq=1

Comment: I am using Macbook Air late 2014. I forgot MacOS version and I can not access to MacOS to check, but maybe MacOS Sierra

Comment: How did you use DiskUtil if you can not boot to macOS?